# Cant Get All results to show on a 4 table query

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

I have a Part table and a Price table
The part table refers to itself to relate to a Warranty Part number.

I want to run a query to show all parts and if they have warranty the part number for the Warranty and then the price.

```
select `P`.`partNumber` AS `partNumber`,`P`.`Description` AS `Description`,`PP`.`Price` AS `Price`,`P`.`WarrantyPartNumber` AS `WarrantyPartNumber`,`W`.`Description` AS `WDescription`
from ((`tblPart` `P` left outer join `tblPart` `W` on `P`.`WarrantyPartNumber` = `W`.`partNumber`)  inner join `tblPartPrice` `PP` on `P`.`partNumber` = `PP`.`partNumber`) 
where PP.tierID = 0
```

the above gives the correct output but without the price. as soon as I add the Warranty PriceList reference I only get Parts with warranty displayed.

```
select `P`.`partNumber` AS `partNumber`,`P`.`Description` AS `Description`,`PP`.`Price` AS `Price`,`P`.`WarrantyPartNumber` AS `WarrantyPartNumber`,`W`.`Description` AS `WDescription`, `wPP`.`Price` AS `wPrice`  
from ((`tblPart` `P` left outer join `tblPart` `W` on `P`.`WarrantyPartNumber` = `W`.`partNumber`)  inner join `tblPartPrice` `PP` on `P`.`partNumber` = `PP`.`partNumber`) right outer join `tblPartPrice` `wPP` on `W`.`partNumber` = `wPP`.`partNumber`
where PP.tierID = 0 AND wPP.tierID = 0
```

**Expected Result**

> All parts with or without warranty showing cost of any warranty
>   elements if present.

Comment: Do all the parts in tblPart have a price in tblPartPrice?

Comment: Yes, In most cases it has 4 prices as I have tiered pricing.

Comment: 'showing cost of any warranty elements' - does that mean there can be many warranty items per part?

Comment: Table: tblPart

Column                  Type Comment
partNumber          varchar(50)  
Shorttitle                  varchar(255)  
Description          varchar(255)  
CategoryID          int(11)  
WarrantyPartNumber varchar(50)

tblpartPrice 
Column             Type Comment
partNumber     varchar(50)  
TierID             float  
Price             float

Comment: No one item will have the option for a single 12 month warranty.

But other cheaper items will not

Comment: I am not clear why would you need to look up WarrantyPartNumber at all when it's on the same row as partnumber, Sample data as text would help clarify.

Comment: You should not use float for integers or for money values , use int and decimal(m,n) instead.

Comment: partNumber,Shorttitle,Description,CategoryID,WarrantyPartNumber
A,,12 Months Extended Warranty for G,0 
B,,12 Months Extended Warranty for H,0 
c,12 Months Extended Warranty for I,0
d,,12 Months Extended Warranty for J,1 
e,,12 Months Extended Warranty for K,1 
f,,12 Months Extended warranty for L,1 
g,,Unit G,0,A
h,,Unit H,0,B
I,,Unit I,0,C
j,, Unit J,0,D
k,,Unit K,0,E
l,,Unit L,0,F

Comment: How do you know in tblpart what is a part and what is a warranty?

Comment: I don't have a field to mark an item as warranty, but have considered adding it to its own catergoy. 

Currently the indication that's its warranty would be if another part refers to it as a Warranty Part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query, fixed up to at least be readable:

```
select p.partNumber, p.Description, pp.Price, 
       pp.WarrantyPartNumber,
       w.Description AS WDescription, wPP.Price AS wPrice
from tblPart p left outer join
     tblPart w
     on p.WarrantyPartNumber = w.partNumber inner join
     tblPartPrice pp
     on p.partNumber = pp.partNumber right outer join
     tblPartPrice wPP
     on w.partNumber = wPP.partNumber
where PP.tierID = 0 AND wPP.tierID = 0;
```

Mixing left and right joins with a `where` clause is just utterly complicated.  Your query seems like something simpler can be used.

If I understand correctly, the tiers must be the same for the warranty parts.  Hence, this condition should be in the `on` clause:

```
select p.partNumber, p.Description, pp.Price, 
       pp.WarrantyPartNumber,
       w.Description AS WDescription, wPP.Price AS wPrice
from tblPart p join
     tblPartPrice pp
     on p.partNumber = pp.partNumber left outer join
     tblPart w
     on p.WarrantyPartNumber = w.partNumber left join
     tblPartPrice wpp
     on w.partNumber = wpp.partNumber and
        wpp.tierID = pp.TierId
where pp.tierID = 0;
```

Note the `join`s:

- `p` **inner join** `pp` because these should match.  You are expecting a price for each part.
- **left join** `w` because there might not be a warranty part
- **left join** `wpp` because the previous `left join` might not have found a matching row.

Comment: That worked a treat thanks. Had to tweak a little:

select p.partNumber, p.Description, pp.Price, 
       p.WarrantyPartNumber,
       w.Description AS WDescription, wpp.Price AS wPrice
from tblPart p join
     tblPartPrice pp
     on p.partNumber = pp.partNumber left outer join
     tblPart w
     on p.WarrantyPartNumber = w.partNumber left join
     tblPartPrice wpp
     on w.partNumber = wpp.partNumber and
        wpp.tierID = pp.TierId
where pp.tierID = 0

but you have saved me a lot of time thank you.